# Neo4j: Find set of nodes that all nodes point to

Tags: neo4j

To be more precise, suppose you have People and Animal nodes, and a `:likes` relationship from `Person` to `Animal`. The question is: How can I find all the `Animal`s that **ALL** the people like?

Example:

```
(Person {name: "Jake"})-[:likes]->(Animal {name: "Dog"})
(Person {name: "Maya"})-[:likes]->(Animal {name: "Dog"})
(Person {name: "Maya"})-[:likes]->(Animal {name: "Snake"})
(Person {name: "Jake"})-[:likes]->(Animal {name: "Cat"})
```

If Jake and Maya are the universe of people, the set of Animals that both Jake and Maya like contains only Dogs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this example dataset:

```
CREATE (jake:Person {name:'Jake'}),
       (maya:Person {name:'Maya'}),
       (dog:Animal {name:'Dog'}),
       (snake:Animal {name:'Snake'}),
       (cat:Animal {name:'Cat'}),
       (jake)-[:LIKES]->(dog),
       (jake)-[:LIKES]->(cat),
       (maya)-[:LIKES]->(dog),
       (maya)-[:LIKES]->(snake)
```

I think the following reads nicely:

```
MATCH (p:Person)
MATCH (a:Animal)

WITH a, COLLECT(p) AS people
WHERE ALL(p IN people WHERE (p)-[:LIKES]->(a))
RETURN a.name
```

http://console.neo4j.org/r/vu3vxp

But it's not as fast as:

```
MATCH (p:Person)
WITH COUNT(p) AS people

MATCH (p:Person)-[:LIKES]->(a:Animal)
WITH a, COUNT(p) AS likes, people
WHERE likes = people
RETURN a.name
```

http://console.neo4j.org/r/nnrvj2

Answer (score 1):

The set of animals (call it "A") that all people like must be either the same as or a subset of the set of animals that a **single** person likes. So, we can speed up the search for A by testing just the animals that a random Person likes.

The following query counts the number of people (np), gets the set of animals that a single person likes (ca), and returns the animals in that set (if any) that are liked by np people.

```
MATCH (p:Person)
WITH COUNT(p) AS np

MATCH (p:Person)-[:LIKES]->(a:Animal)
WITH p, COLLECT(a) AS ca, np
LIMIT 1

UNWIND ca AS a
MATCH (x:Person)-[:LIKES]->(a)
WITH a, COUNT(x) AS nx, np
WHERE nx = np
RETURN COLLECT(a) AS result;
```

Comment: This is great, thanks! Going with the other answer for terseness.